# COPY unsuccessful with Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

tried to comment on another post, but got some message about not
having enough of a comment quota to do that.

Here's what I was asking about:

"Docker doesn't expand ~ or $HOME. You probably need to reference the file explicitly, or package it relative to the Dockerfile itself."

I tried what was suggested and the COPY still doesn't work as in:

```
COPY /home/ubuntu/source/ /home/ubuntu/dest/
```

Does anyone know what else I am missing?

Thank you.

Additional question: is /home/ubuntu/source/ my context?

Another additional question:  I am now getting:

> /home/ubuntu/source: no such file or directory.

why?

Comment: Typo in the COPY statement, I think the forum editor zapped some of what I typed.  Attempted COPY is:  COPY /home/ubuntu/source/ /home/ubuntu/destination/ ...........and is not working.

Comment: If you are the owner of the other post, you can edit your post. Do not comment like here. If your are not the owner you can answer. Some will blame you for that, but that your only change to reply until you have enough points. To your question: the COPY statement copies files from your host machine into your docker instance. Do you try to copy inside of your instance? Then use the unix command `CMD cp ...`

Comment: I did a mkdir -p on the destination directory before the COPY.  Shouldn't that have done it?  I've got a bigger problem now that my docker build can't see my source directory.  I have no idea WHERE that is coming from.   But back to the other problem, the mkdir doesn't work either.  And should my WORKDIR be the /home/ubuntu/source directory?